# How to go VTEC with a D16A8 DOHC engine

Tags: engine, honda, vtec, modification

Living in South Africa.

I have a 160E Honda Ballade ABS and a D16A8 motor.

Need to go VTEC BT, not sure if I can go F18 SOHC VTEC, replacing the engine and gearbox and management.

Is it possible to put a VTEC system on the D16 DOHC without going to the B-series?  South Africa stock on B-series is expensive.

Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the make/model/year of your chassis?  What year VTEC engine do you want to put in the chassis?  Are you trying to get away with only using VTEC heads?  Your question is very unclear.  Help us be successful helping you and add in everything you can think.  Regarding cost, we don't do that here.  We are technical strictly.  Thanks and welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: If you can't answer the questions to tighten down an answer, this question is too broad.  If you can add the related info I would be happy to vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 4):

The D16A8 engine is the equivalent to the ZC DOHC engine  (non-vtec). The VTEC head from the D16Y8 **will not** bolt on. Neither will the head from a B16A1.

The head on the D16A8 is superior to that of the D16Y8 even without the VTEC. It flows better and really likes to be turbocharged. I suggest you turbocharge the engine instead of an engine swap. Cheaper and more power.

The stock D16A8 engine is will stand up to 250whp on stock pistons and rods. You can achieve that with a small turbo at about one bar. Anything else will require changing the internals.

A low cost way of improving the internals is to use Suzuki Vitara 1.6 pistons with some aftermarket rods.